# Jdbc connection pool and mysql thread pool

Tags: java, mysql, performance, jdbc

I use mysql jdbc connection pool. Should I use mysql thread pool in addition to improve performance?

Answer (score 0):

mysql thread pool works on the server. The connection pool is on the client (locally), it stores the connection so they don't have to be initiated again and again. The thread pool on mysql server, handles pool of workers that will actually communicate with clients to perform the sql operations..

Answer (score 0):

I think that for connections handling, you should use something like the SharedPoolDataSource ([org.apache.commons.dbcp2](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/)).
We have it in running on production, and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that thread/connection pooling is low on the list of bottlenecks.  I suggest you first check your tuning, your queries, and your indexes.  If you have a particular web page or process that is slow, add timers to it to see which part is the slowest.  If it turns out to be, say, a SELECT, then show us the SELECT, plus the CREATE TABLE.  *That* is the most likely bottleneck.